# CSS background image versus navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a bit of a time with my wordpress theme and making it so that my background image of the first div is NOT clipped off by the navbar. Currently the top of the image is getting eaten behind the menu. I feel dumb for not being able to make it work. Resizing the image to add empty space might help but I'd rather try to do a CSS fix if possible. You can see whats currently happening on my page at http://www.cswu1611.org/home

Z-index doesn't seem to work and absolute positioning is troublesome as I need it to remain responsive.

(I know I'm not a fan of how the site is turning out myself but at this point the clients are so insistent and picky I gotta try to make it work this way)

For reference the theme is X from theme.co and I've contacted them for support but multiple times their solutions haven't been great.

Comment: Generally, unless it's a design choice, the TOP padding on the body for the page, when the header is fixed, is equal to the height of the navbar. See the fixed header example in the examples at GetBootstrap.com click on the starter-template.css. In this way anchor links and the other stuff is not covered up by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page was built oddly, I see that you didn't code it, but anyway, here you go:

```
.bg-image.parallax.man {background-position:center 70px}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution seems to work however the HTML seems to be overriding it even if I set !important. So if I change it in the developer tools and edit the CSS its' fine but the wordpress code is having none of it.

Comment: Stick it last in all your css.

Comment: My CMS caches, so I tend to have to clear it after I add css or js unless this is turned off.

Comment: Think this got it actually.

Comment: Might want to just target the first child of the parent div on the entire wrapper. It's doing it to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do a couple of things to make this better. Without the code or fiddle I can't help you too much but I will try.

1. Decrease the padding of the navbar so that it isn't so tall
2. Make the grey color of the navbar a little bit transparent using `background:rgba(#,#,#,0.5)` with the # being the rgb values and the 0.5 meaning it has 0.5 opacity.
3. Make the navbar have a `position:absolute;` with `top:0;`
   Then you `transform:translateY(#)` the div with the # being the height of the navbar.

There are different ways to do this but without a fiddle it's hard to show you.

Comment: Yes I am aware its not much to go on but I'm a bit overwhelmed by what all would be needed to be put in fiddle with all the moving parts going on between my own css, the theme, the visual composer code (Which is custom built by the theme devs to boot) I wouldn't know where to begin. I'll give these some tries and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the background position on the image.  At the largest size, you appear to have 94px of top bar and navigation for the first image, so setting the image background position to `background-position: 50% 94px;` does the trick.  Subsequent images would be at 60px as the top bar scrolls away.

That said, you'll have to make adjustments for each breakpoint if the nav height changes, which it currently does for me (and perhaps incremental ones for the first image where the top bar wraps on to multiple lines).